# Makefile works %.c, does not work %.cpp

Tags: c++, gnu-make

I have a set of makefiles I use to build a 'big' C project.  I am now trying to reuse some in my C++ project and have run into this headache that I just cannot figure out.

The makefile looks like this

```
SOURCES = \
elements/blue.cpp

# Dont edit anything below here

VPATH = $(addprefix $(SOURCE_DIR)/, $(dir $(SOURCES)))

CXXFLAGS = $(OPT_FLAGS) -MMD -MF $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.d -D_LINUX -DNDEBUG -pipe
DCXXFLAGS = $(DEBUG_FLAGS) -MMD -MF $(BUILD_DIR)/$*.d -v -D_LINUX -D_DEBUG -pipe

OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/Release/%.o, $(notdir $(SOURCES)))
DOBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/Debug/%.o, $(notdir $(SOURCES)))

$(OBJECTS): $(BUILD_DIR)/Release/%.o: %.cpp
    +@[ -d $(dir $@) ] || mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CPP) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -o $@ -c $<
```

Its a little complicated but what it does in C is build all the %.c files defined in SOURCES and put the object files in BUILD_DIR.  It works great in c, but this does not work with cpp files.  I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `blue.cpp', needed by `build/Release/blue.o'.  Stop.
```

Its like VPATH is not working at all.  I tried

```
vpath %.cpp src/elements
```

but that does not work either.

Amazingly enough, renaming blue.cpp to blue.c and editing the makefile back to the %.c usage does work, it compiles just fine.

Am I going crazy here?

Comment: are you saying that the only difference between this and the working C version is that in the working version .c replaces .cpp globally?

Comment: @Neil, sounds like the default C rule is kicking in and compiling the files, and there is no explicit c++ rule.

Comment: @Neil, yes, the only difference between the working and non-working is %.c and the filename of the source

Comment: @Charles Try renaming a .cpp file as .cc and build with the C++ makefile - there is an implicit rule to do .cc to .o, so that should test the implicit rule theory.

Comment: Yea, what Neil says. He probably knows better than I do.

Comment: ok, renamed the file to .cc and changed all the %.cpp to %.cc and it did not work either.  I renamed the file to .c again, removed the $(OBJECTS): $(BUILD_DIR)/Release/%.o: %.c rule and it does not work.  (it did work with the rule)

Comment: I seem to remember that some version of gmake needed a .SUFFIXES: .cpp to make implicit rules with .cpp files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I figured it out here and its a big mess of a bug.

After some more experimentation I went to post a bug on the make-bugs list and turned on debug output to tell them exactly what was going on.  Turns out I should have done this before because it led me right to the solution.

I use an automatic dependency generation scheme developed from http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html and amazingly enough that was breaking make.  Trouble occurred in with this line

```
-include $(patsubst %.c, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.d, $(notdir $(SOURCES)))
```

I did not change that to %.cpp and for some reason trying to include blue.cpp caused make to not search for it using vpath when it tried to resolve

```
$(OBJECTS): $(BUILD_DIR)/Release/%.o: %.cpp
```

So the solution was just to port the makefile correctly, doh!

Answer (score 3):

From your example, it looks like you don't have a Makefile rule being activated for compiling the C++ files. Maybe your `%` are expanding incorrectly?

Try

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp
    ...
```

And specify the destination in the rule part, using `$(basename ..)` where appropriate.

It works for C for `blue.c` because Make has a **[built-in default rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules)** for compiling C files. I suspect running Make with the `--no-builtin-rules` option would cause the `blue.c` file to stop working too.

From the docs,

> Compiling C programs
>       n.o is made automatically from n.c with a command of the form `$(CC) -c
>   $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)'. Compiling C++
>   programs
>       n.o is made automatically from n.cc, n.cpp, or n.C with a command of
>   the form`$(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS)
>   $(CXXFLAGS)'. We encourage you to use
>   the suffix `.cc' for C++ source files
>   instead of`.C'.

There *is* a default C++ rule, but it might not be kicking in for you because of another rule or bad variables. It is better to write the rule explicitly to be sure.

You need a rule such as:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPP_OPTS) -c -o $@ $<
```

For compiling your object files from source, then you have:

```
executable: $(OBJECTS)
    ... compile objects into final blob ...
```

Where the objects of some format `%.o` trigger the dependency. Or use [Autotools/Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) to build your Makefile for you. Here is an example I wrote that just builds C++ files into a directory of objects:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard path/to/src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES: .cpp=.o)
CC=g++

final: $(OBJECTS)
    mv $(OBJECTS) /path/to/build_dir

%.o: %.cpp:
    g++ -c -o $@ $<
```

Not a complete example by any means, but you get the idea. In the `final` rule, you copy the object files, but you can do whatever here or change the `-o` option to plonk build files in a specific location.

Comment: What about: $(OBJECTS): $(BUILD_DIR)/Release/%.o: %.cpp

Comment: BUt I do define the C++ build rule, its the $(OBJECTS): $(BUILD_DIR)/Release/%.o: %.cpp line in there, kind of hard to pick out

Comment: That rule isn't being activated. Break it up into a simpler form first. I suspect some expansion of `%` is happening incorrectly.

Comment: I tried running make on my old project with --no-builtin-rules and it worked fine.  But the expansion problem is at least a lead I can look farther into, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need VPATH - I've had nothing but trouble with it in the past. And in fact, I seem to remember that VPATH is dependent on extensions, so that would fit Aiden's theory. In my makefiles, I give the source directory SDIR explicitly:

```
SDIR = ./somewhere
... 
$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CC) -c $(INC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

.

**Edit:** If you are wedded to the use of VPATH, then you need to investigate the use of the vpath directive (note case difference). For example:

```
vpath %.cpp foo:bar
```

looks for .cpp fies in foo and bar directories. But as I said, I've had nothing but trouble using this.

Comment: When this gets confirmed. I will delete my waffle ;), also +1 for generally good advice

Comment: I wish I did not need to use it, like you said its a very devilish little variable.  Trouble is my source folders are not flat, and I cannot have my bin folder ending up with the same directory tree structure that exists in the src dir.
Using the vpath like this was my solution, and it took weeks to get right, that being said, it there is a better way I am all for it.
I will try setting up up to not use the vpath and see what happens.

Comment: not using vpath works perfectly. eugggg vpaths, now I need to new solution to the build dir path problem.

Comment: Either way, VPATH voodoo is never good. I'm with Neil on being explicit. Some resolution/expansion is bad, at some level between VPATH, your variable creation and the what the rule expands to. Try echoing the $< and $@