# C++ Makefile %.c works, %.cpp not?

Tags: c++, makefile

i wrting a simple makefile for c++ files but here is a problem i do not understand.
I have 2 folders

/src   for .cpp files

- main.cpp
- check cpp

/include for .hpp files

- check.hpp

My Makefiles looks like this

```
LIBS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
CC   = g++
VPATH = src include
CPPFLAGS = -I include

### Files ###
OBJ = main.o check.o

### Rules ###
all: sfml-app

sfml-app: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o sfml-app $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf *o $(OBJ)
```

if i use my makefile likes this, everything works fine.
But if i change **%.o: %.c** to **%.o: %.cpp** he said

```
src/main.cpp:2:21: critical  error: check.hpp: file or folder not found
```

is it wrong to write .cpp instead of .c even it is a c++ project? This confused me a bit. Why .c works finde and .cpp not.

thanks for your help :) !

Comment: `CC = g++` - ***WRONG***

Comment: @H2CO3 Actually you *need* this rule unless you overload the automatic rule for linking (don’t!) since `make` uses `$(CC)` for linking, *not* `$(LD)`, at least on my system (and as far as I know this is pretty normal).

Comment: You’re getting a compile error. Post your `main.cpp` file. Does `main.hpp` exist in the correct folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136294/makefile-works-c-does-not-work-cpp

Comment: @KonradRudolph `CC` is conceptually (and as an implicit rule in GNU make) the C compiler. For compiling C++, one uses `CXX`. `CC = g++` ***is wrong.***

Comment: @H2CO3 Well like I said, in that case you’d need to change the the linking rule as well. The GNU tool chain is simply inconsistent in this regard.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, and agreed on "don't!" :)

Comment: The Problem was what MadScientist sad. I forget to the $(CPPFLAGS).
But @ H2CO3, did your answer meen i should use CXX = g++ instead of CC = g++ ?

Comment: Yes you should use `CXX` for compiling C++.  `CC` is for compiling C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flags variable for the C++ language is called `CXXFLAGS`, and you should be using `$(CXX)` instead of `$(CC)` in your code. `CPPFLAGS` is the variable for preprocessor arguments.

Comment: Just to note, he _is_ using `CPPFLAGS` for preprocessor arguments: `-I` is a preprocessor argument.  The only variable wrong is, as you mention, he should be using `CXX` not `CC` for the C++ compiler.

Comment: Diffferent preprocessor arguments. CPPFLAGS is used when you use `$(CPP) myfile.txt_pp > myfile.txt` - that is, you are using the C preproessor to modify a text file, or some other "not for C compiler" content (or if you preprocess before compiling for some reason)

Comment: If you are using the `cpp` (or the `$(CPP)` macro) command to preprocess files, `CPPFLAGS`, if you are using `g++` or the `$(CXX)` macro, or  some other C++ compiler, `CXXFLAGS`. Both are valid variables, but the correct one for the above makefile is `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: No, `CFLAGS` is for the C compiler.

Comment: Mats, that's not correct.  `CPPFLAGS` is for all preprocessor flags.  The reason you break them out separately from `CFLAGS` is so that you can pass them to tools which want to preprocess your source code, but not compile it (so they don't accept the compiler flags).  The prime example, from back when make was very young, is `lint`, but there are plenty of others.  You want those tools to use the same `-I` and `-D` flags that your compilation uses, so you you put them in `CPPFLAGS`, then when you compile you use both `CFLAGS` (for C) or `CXXFLAGS` (for C++) _AND_ `CPPFLAGS`, together.

Comment: If you look at the default rules for compiling that are built into make, you'll see that all compilation and linker rules (for C, C++, Fortran, assembler, preprocessor, etc.) include `CPPFLAGS` as part of the rule, plus language-specific variables like `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS, `FFLAGS`, etc.

Comment: Also just to note, this answer doesn't address either of the questions asked: (1) why does changing `%.o : %.c` to `%.o : %.cpp` cause problems, and (2) why does the compile fail.  This answer is just discussing common and recommended styles: your makefile will still work (if you write it properly) even if you name your variables `BLAH`, `BARF`, and `BLECH` instead of `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`.  People reading it will not be happy, but it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Because make is trying to build a `.o` from a `.cpp` file, when you write a rule like `%.o : %.c` it has no effect on make because make is not trying to build a `.o` from a `.c`.  Because of that, make is using its own built-in rules to compile the `.cpp` file into the `.o` file and the built-in rule works fine.

When you change the rule to be `%.o : %.cpp`, now your rule matches what make wants to build and so make uses *your* rule instead of its own built-in rule.  Obviously your rule is broken and does not work.

Why does it not work?  Because you are not using `$(CPPFLAGS)`, and so the `-I include` flags are not passed to the compiler, and so the compiler cannot find your header files.

Answer (score 1):

Use standard make file flags

CXX for g++
CPP for cpp files

and try:

```
%.o: %.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

Answer (score 1):

The default rules are:

For C files:

```
$(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $?
```

For C++ files

```
$(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $?
```

For linking:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LOADLIBES)
```

CPPFLAGS is supposed to be pre-processor flags. The other two (CFLAGS CXXFLAGS) are flags for the specific languages. You should adjust your usage as such.

Also it is unusual to exlicitly define the object files:

```
OBJ = main.o check.o
```

It is more usual to define the source files. Then define object files in terms of the source files

```
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRC))
```

Personally I like to build everything in the directory so use

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
```

But this will depend a lot on the project.

Comment: Thanks ! I personally prefer
that makefiles list the files they want to compile explicitly, and not try to get them via wildcard.  The latter is very error-prone: extra
files might exist and be accidentally compiled; files may be missing and not be compiled, etc.   But you are right, i should write the source files, not the object files. patsubst very helpful :) !